# Unable to use xpra: "Authorisation not recognised"

Tags: x11, raspberry-pi, remote-desktop, xpra

After some trickery that I learned from [the answer to this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50000/cannot-install-xpra-unmet-dependancies) I, too, managed to install xpra on my Raspberry Pi. I'm able to run graphical applications just fine without xpra, but after I start xpra, nothing works:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ xpra start :10
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ Entering daemon mode; any further errors will be reported to:
  /home/pi/.xpra/:10.log

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iceweasel &
[1] 23660
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ MobaXterm X11 proxy: Authorisation not recognised
Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0

[1]+  Exit 1                  iceweasel
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

What could possibly be wrong? I've read about the "Authorisation not recognized" error and about something called the "MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1", but everything that I can find concerns running the application as a different user, i.e. after `su` or `sudo`, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

```
xpra start :10 --start=iceweasel
```

(note: the application will be running in xpra's virtual framebuffer and won't be visible until you use `xpra attach` to connect to it)